# I was making a random anime selector in python and I can't seem to get where the error is.Could somebody help me out with this project

Tags: python

I have tried searching for a solution but haven't found  an answer yet

```
from random import choice
#create a list of animes and insert their genres

Myanimes= {

   "Action":["One Punch Man","Demon Slayer","Vinland Saga","Baki","Baki Hanma","Full Metal alchemist:brotherhood","Yasuke","Dragon Ball Z","Dragon Ball Super"],
   
   "Adventure":["My hero academia "," Black Clover","Naruto","Cowboy Bebop"],
   
   "Supernatural":["Blue exorcist","Jojo's Bizarre Adventure"],
   
   "Sci-fi":["Attack on Titan","Assasination Classroom","Parasyte"],
   
   "Fantasy":["Jujustsu Kaisen","Hunter x Hunter","Devilman Crybaby"],
   
   "Comedy":["Komi Can't Communicate"],
   
   "Drama":["Food Wars","The Disastrous Life of Saiki K"],
   
   "Psychological":["Code Geass","Mob Pyscho","Death Note"],
   
   "Horror":["Castlevania","Record of Ragnarok"],



   
}
print(choice(Myanimes))
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 4
```

I keep getting a key error 4 but if you find any other errors please help me correct them.

Comment: choice works only with list, Myanimes its dict

Comment: As @VitaliyKorolyk said, `choice` works only on lists. So you could randomly select a genre first and use that to access the right list, e.g. `genre = choice(list(my_animes.keys())); print(choice(my_animes[genre]))`

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, `random.choice` works with lists and not with dicts. You have two options:

1. Use the list of the keys of the dict:

```
genre=choice(list(Myanimes.keys()))
print(genre, Myanimes[genre])
# Result: Fantasy ['Jujustsu Kaisen', 'Hunter x Hunter', 'Devilman Crybaby']
```

2. Use the list of items, which are `(key, value)` pairs

```
print(choice(list(Myanimes.items())))
# Result: ('Supernatural', ['Blue exorcist', "Jojo's Bizarre Adventure"])
```